# Angular Data-Grid is not generating with a default pageSize

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, grid

I am using [Data-Grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-data-grid) for listing of my grid data. However, I have to say maximum item per page from the grid. I have gone through the Data-Grid library function and changed the parameters from there to select the customize / selact my default value. But, I am failed. It's appearing here in some way [image]

Here the problem is it's not selecting the default page size when loading. So I have done so to select the default page size in this way

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: [],
        getData: gridListService.getOrdersDataItemcategory,
        sort: {
            predicate: 'Name',
            direction: 'asc'
        },
        itemsPerPage:5,
    };
```

However it's still not working. But, once, when I select any item from the `dropdown` like 5/10 then the pagination appears and obey by the the item per pages this way. [image]

So, now, my question is how can I start from this way which will select a default pagesize rather than coming with a empty value with all items. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, I got the solution by myself. I have added the default `itemsPerPage` in the wrong way. it will be this way.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: [],
        getData: gridListService.getOrdersDataItemcategory,
        sort: {
            predicate: 'Name',
            direction: 'asc'
        },
        pagination: {
            itemsPerPage: '10'
        }
    };
```

Here the pagination support is coming from the another angular module as there are 2 `js` file(`datagrid, and pagination`). [Source file](http://angular-data-grid.github.io/demo/100k/js/demoApp.js)